# Warning on NonSdkApiUsedViolation after submitting Cordova App on PlayStore

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

i want to submit an app on playStore, but Google refused it for using non sdk Api.

I am using Cordova to create this App.

So the warning is :

```
StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Landroid/media/AudioManager;->getOutputLatency(I)I
    at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:407)
    at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.getPublicMethodRecursive(Class.java:2079)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2066)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1693)
    at org.chromium.media.AudioManagerAndroid.<clinit>(PG:4)
```

Below the list of plugins are used on my App :

- cordova-plugin-android-permissions 1.1.2 "Permissions"
- cordova-plugin-appinfo 2.1.2 "AppInfo Plugin"
- cordova-plugin-camera 5.0.0 "Camera"
- cordova-plugin-console 1.1.0 "Console"
- cordova-plugin-device 2.0.3 "Device"
- cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.7.1 "File Transfer"
- cordova-plugin-file 6.0.2 "File"
- cordova-plugin-media-capture 3.0.3 "Capture"
- cordova-plugin-media 5.0.3 "Media"
- cordova-plugin-navigationbar 1.0.31 "Cordova NavigationBar plugin"
- cordova-plugin-splashscreen 6.0.0 "Splashscreen"
- cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.3 "StatusBar"
- cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.4 "Whitelist"
- ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
- org.devgeeks.Canvas2ImagePlugin 0.6.0 "Canvas 2 Image"

Have you any idea about this problem ?

Comment: Having the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: I'm also facing this issue last two days but didn't find any solution. But you guys once check out this link. https://forum.unity.com/threads/google-play-api-warnings-started-today.676654/page-4

Comment: Hi, Did you find any solution for this.
In fact - I had the similar issue but despite the issue it release the app to the Prod.
Sample: Non-SDK API :=>
Landroid/media/AudioManager;->getOutputLatency(I)I